# Last Digit of alternating factorials

Tags: number-theory

I noticed that the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k k!
$$
has last digit $1$ or $9$ if $m$ is greater than $3$ but no other number. Can someone figure out why this holds?

Comment: What is the context of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $5! = 120$. What can you conclude about the units digit?

Comment: So every number with 5 as a factor in it has last digit $0$ or $5$ and then we add 19 because of $4!-3!+2!-1!=19$.

Comment: Ok I got it now

Comment: Actually, more precisely, $n!$, if $n \ge 5,$ always ends in the digit $0$ because it is divisible by both $2$ and $5$. You sort of implied above that some of the numbers have last digit $5$, which is not correct.